# Add Today Extension to Cordova project

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-cli

I have a directory of "Today Extension" project.

I want to add the project to my Cordova project, one may know the platform directory in the Cordova project when I run the command

**CLI: "cordova platform add ios"**

is automatically generated and couldn't be added through Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a target to an existing XCode project is something that can be done using node with the `xcode` package or through ruby using `xcodeproj`. The exact method on how to do so, however, is something I haven't figured out yet and I'm also very interested in.

So far, I have found [one resource](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch) where they actually add a watchkit extension, but I haven't had the time to look into this in much depth. Also I think I myself lack the skill to generalize this into a plugin.